# code not deploy on firebase cloud

Tags: android

this is an error on my project when deploying our project on firebase cloud .please tells me a solution to this problem

```
C:\Users\Cloud Analogy\Desktop\Notifications\functions>firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'rideservices-620cc'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Cloud Analogy\Desktop\Notifications\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Cloud Analogy\Desktop\Notifications\%RESOURCE_DIR%\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cloud Analogy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-27T19_50_57_450Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code4294963238

C:\Users\Cloud Analogy\Desktop\Notifications\functions>"predeploy": [
'"predeploy":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Cloud Analogy\Desktop\Notifications\functions>"npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint"
'"npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up `Firebase.json` and change predeloy to:

```
{
  ...  // your config
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
  ... // your config
}
```

Comment: Thank You, @James

Comment: I am facing one problem again please visit a link and solve my problem. this is a link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127725/navigation-stack-activity-switcher-in-android)